# Is $\aleph_{\alpha+1}^{\aleph_a} > \aleph_\alpha^{\aleph_a}$ true?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I'm trying to determine if $\aleph_{\alpha+1}^{\aleph_a} > \aleph_\alpha^{\aleph_a}$ is true for some ordinal $\alpha$. I don't think $\aleph_{\alpha+1} > \aleph_\alpha$ necessarily implies it just because of the way $\aleph$'s work. Or can I just assume that?

Any advice would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: There is clearly an injection in one direction, implying $\geq$ at the very least.

Comment: The exponent has index $a$ and the bases index of $\alpha$ (and $\alpha+1$). Are those supposed to be the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that $$2^\kappa \le \kappa^{\kappa} \le (2^{\kappa})^\kappa = 2^{\kappa \times \kappa} = 2^{\kappa}$$
so equality holds throughout and so $\kappa^\kappa = 2^\kappa$.

And notice that $$2^{\aleph_\alpha} \le \aleph_{\alpha+1}^{\aleph_\alpha} \le (2^{\aleph_\alpha})^{\aleph_\alpha}$$

where the latter comes from noting that $2^{\aleph_\alpha}$ is bigger than $\aleph_\alpha$, but $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ is the smallest cardinal bigger than $\aleph_\alpha$. So again equality holds throughout, because $(2^{\aleph_\alpha})^{\aleph_\alpha} = 2^{\aleph_\alpha}$.